# Node.js command-line utilities : how to insure module accessibility?

Tags: node.js, module

So, in writing command-line utilities with node, if my command requires certain modules, should I include a package.json file to list those dependencies? Obviously this will require running `> npm install` on the package file.

Without doing so, packages are not found, even though I've installed them globally. How are others distributing these types of cli scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if my command requires certain modules, should I include a package.json file to list those dependencies?

Yes. This is standard.

> Obviously this will require running `> npm install` on the package file.

This isn't exactly the case.  You have to run `npm install` during development to initialize your environment. However, if someone installs your script through npm (e.g. `npm install -g your-script-name`), the dependencies for your script will automatically be installed.  This is a recursive operation, meaning the dependencies of your dependencies will be installed as well, and so on.